# Proof explanation: Cayley's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

Cayley's Theorem (in my class): Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Then, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

I trying my best to understand the proof of this theorem, but can't seem to fully grasp it. My biggest problem area is understanding what exactly is described by $\phi$, the isomorphism used in the proof. Can someone describe $\phi $ both informally and formally?

Comment: What is the proof that was presented to you ?

Comment: Quicky: for any $\;g\;$, the $\;n\;$ products $\;gx\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb G\;$ define a permutation on the $\;n\;$ letters that are the elements of $\;G\;$ . You identify the group of permutations with $\;S_n\;$ and the above permutation defined by $\;g\;$ via the homomorphism $\;\phi\;$ . There must be tens of thousands of pages in the web which deal with this, and there must just be one that you will find nice to read and understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an informal argument:

You want to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ (for $n=\vert G\vert$). Well, how do you show that something is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$? *Actions!* Elements of $S_n$ are understood by how they permute the set $[n]=\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$. So in order to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, what we need is a machine for doing the following:

- Take in a $g\in G$.
- Spit out a permutation $\pi_g\in S_n$.

The hope is that the map $h: G\rightarrow S_n: g\mapsto \pi_g$ will be a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_n$, and that it will be injective; then $G$ will be isomorphic to $im(h)$.

So this boils down to:

> How can I think of an element of $g$ as permuting some $n$-element set?

This is hard because $G$ is an abstract group - we have no sense of what $G$ is "meant to do." So we have to cook up some interpretation of $G$ from scratch!

Luckily, there is a natural $n$-element set lying around: $G$ itself! So, is there a way we can think of an element of $G$ permuting the whole set $G$?

The answer is: yes! Given an element $g$, consider the map from $G$ to $G$ defined as $$\pi_g: a\mapsto g\cdot a.$$ Each $\pi_g$ is a permutation of $G$, we have $\pi_g=\pi_h$ iff $g=h$, and $\pi_g\circ \pi_h=\pi_{gh}$ (do you see why these facts are true?); so the map $h: g\mapsto \pi_g$ is in fact an *injective group homomorphism* from $G$ to the group of permutations of $G$ . . .

. . . but this latter group is just $S_n$, renamed!

Comment: I loved the easy flowing writing style, it takes an effort to write this clearly.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For $g\in G$, denote $\phi_g:x\mapsto gx$

$\phi_g$ is a permutation of G.

What's more $\phi_g \circ\phi_{g'} = \phi_{gg'}$ and $\phi_e = id$, thus $\{\phi_g, g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathfrak S(G)$ (the set of permutations of $G$)

Now consider the function $f:g\mapsto\phi_g$. We will prove that $f$ is an isomorphism and this will be Cayley's Theorem.

First see that 
$f(g)\circ f(g') = f(gg')$ (see above)

Then note
$f(g)=id \iff g=e$ thus $\ker f = e$ and therefore $f$ is injective. Since $G$ is finite of order n, and so is $\{\phi_g, g\in G\}$, what follows is that $f$ is bijective and is therefore an isomorphism.

Thus $G$ and $\{\phi_g, g\in G\}$ are isomorphic, and since $\{\phi_g, g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathfrak S(G)$, we deduce that G is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$