# How to turn any group into a set of symmetries equipped with composition?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

Let's say you have a group like $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, where it’s not immediately clear where the symmetries are (compared to a group $(S, \circ)$ which is a group of symmetries of some object equipped with composition).

I'm trying to come up with a procedure to turn any group into another group where the symmetries are more obvious.

On a high level, I can use Cayley's theorem to find a subgroup of a symmetric group that is isomorphic to my original group.

I want to know what happens on a low level. My current hypothesis is that you consider the symmetries of the group itself, put them in a set, and equip these transformations with composition, you get the group I'm looking for. I presume what I have described is Cayley's theorem itself.

This checks out for the group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, where the symmetries of the group are the translations on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is what I'm saying correct?

Comment: Yes, Cayley means that multiplication in a group $G$  is also a group action of $G$ on the set $G.$ For some groups, it is more obvious what the symmetries are. For example, $(\mathbb R,+)$ is the collection of permutations $\sigma$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $\sigma(a)-\sigma(b)=a-b$ for all $a,b.$ This can be seen as order-preserving isometries on $\mathbb R.$ Finite groups can always be represented as the symmetries of an edge-colored directed graph, of course.

Comment: You can do the same for infinite groups, but that representation is far from an intuitive object for infinite groups.

Comment: [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4405814/28111) to your previous question describes exactly this. And yes, as I say there this is just Cayley's theorem itself.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I guess I'm just shocked that Cayley's theorem is so simple, I thought I'd made a mistake and wanted to double check.

Comment: @DavideRadaelli Nope, it's really that simple. (Like any good simple theorem it has plenty complicated follow-ups, but that's a separate story.)

Comment: Incidentally, is there any aspect of this question not addressed by my answer to your previous one?

Comment: I didn't make the link that what happens with Cayley's theorem is that you find the symmetries of the *group* itself, and equip it with composition (and this new group is isomorphic to the old).

Comment: Any object in math can be turned into a symmetry group by considering its symmetries. Even groups themselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134910/discussion-between-davide-radaelli-and-noah-schweber).